# Issue while capturing SFTP output to variable

Tags: shell, unix, sh, sftp

I am not able to store output of below **SFTP** command to result variable.
The command is

```
result=`sftp -oPort=$p_port $p_ftp_user_id@$p_host <<EOF
                    cd $p_remote_dir
                    mget TEST_FEED*
                    rm TEST_FEED*
                    exit
EOF`
echo "$result"
```

When is fire above command in a shell script output err is like below:

> Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: dora:0.0 Host key verification
>   failed. Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

I want this error to be stored in *result* variable so that i can use it for below validation:

```
value2=`echo "$result" |grep "failed" |wc -l`
```

But i getting *result* as empty. Please help what i m missing here.

Comment: Also tried like below but still facing same issue, result="$( sftp -oPort=$p_port $p_ftp_user_id@$p_host <<EOF
                    cd $p_remote_dir
                    mget TEST_FEED*
                    rm TEST_FEED*
                    exit
EOF
)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should redirect stderr to stdout for `sftp` command using `2>&1`

```
result=$(sftp -oPort=$p_port $p_ftp_user_id@$p_host <<EOF 2>&1
cd $p_remote_dir
mget TEST_FEED*
rm TEST_FEED*
exit
EOF
)

echo "$result"
```

Comment: Result is still NULL. This time there is no error message printed after script execution. Can you elaborate what is 2>/dev/null and how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. Try it now.

Comment: Yes, it works now.Thank you.can you explain how this 2>&1 redirects output. I just need to get some idea about this syntax. Thanks

Comment: `2>&1` sends stderr to stdout, which is being captured using `$(...)`